# Closed loop system of servo motor for master and slave flex

Tags: servo, closed-loop

I am really new in Arduino. So what I have is two flex sensor, a master flex for the left hand and a slave flex for the right hand. What it will do is that when the master flex is bent, the servo motor will run and adjust to the angle the flex is at. Now what I want to happen is that the there will be a feedback so that the slave flex will autocorrect itself in order to have the same value as that of the master flex. This is my code and circuit in TinkerCAD atm and I can't seem to do it and tried various code but can't seem to do the closed loop/autocorrection of this circuit.

[image]

Comment: Please _edit your question_ taking the following into account: Reading code is bad enough.  Reading an _image_ of code is worse.  Please include a code block with your code.  When you finish that, give us an idea of how the servo is mechanically connected to the slave flex.  Let us know if leaving the servo unpowered and flexing the master and slave register with the program.  Then, finally, you tell us what is _actually doing_, in more detail than "not working".

Comment: _"the slave flex will autocorrect **itself**"_ - you mean the servo moves the slave flex, right?